# How do I programatically create a context?

Tags: blocks, migrations, 7

I'm using the migrate module to move content into a Drupal site. Some of this content needs to be created as blocks and added to a region using contexts. I have the creation of blocks (actually, boxes) working using a purpose-built module, but I don't know where to begin on the context side of things - looking for something like `add_block_to_context()` but I cannot find anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

After checking the code used in the [context test](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!context!tests!context.conditions.test/function/ContextConditionContextTest%3a%3atest/6) units for Drupal 6:

```
ctools_include('export');
$context = ctools_export_new_object('context');
$context->name = 'testcontext';
$context->conditions = array('path' => array('values' => array('admin')));
$context->reactions = array('debug' => array('debug' => TRUE));
$saved = context_save($context);
```

You can easily code your reactions or conditions then save the context.

BTW to get all context you can use [context_context_list()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/context_context_list/7).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, is to actually create the full context with all blocks first and then export it, using the built in export option or features.

Comment: I'm talking hundreds of blocks here, so it would be much better if I can automate this

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using below codes.

Before that use context to export all values to check blocks array format or some structure.

```
$context = new stdClass();
$context->disabled = FALSE;
$context->api_version = 3;
$context->name = 'name-of-context';
$context->description = 'Description';
$context->tag = '';
$context->conditions = array(
'path' => array(
  'values' => array(
    'node/120' => 'node/120',
  ),
),
);
$context->reactions = array(
'block' => array(
  'blocks' => call_function_to_generate_block_array(),
),
'theme_html' => array(
  'class' => 'myclass',
),
);
$context->condition_mode = 0;
context_save($context);
```

***Note:*** you can save all these values into one script file & can use`drush scr script.php` command to execute it.